# Tomcat 7 remote debugging on EC2

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7, remote-debugging

I have a tomcat 7 instance running on EC2. The port that tomcat is running on is its default, 8080.

I wanna start tomcat in debug mode, so I started tomcat with the following command :

```
sudo service tomcat7 start -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
```

I have 8000 port opened in my security group. But when I try to remote debug using eclipse, it gives me a Connection refused error. Any clue what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks..

Comment: Amazon Linux AMI release 2013.09

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think that you can put the debug options as arguments to the `service` command.

Assuming you installed the standard `tomcat7` package using `yum`, edit the file `/etc/tomcat7/tomcat7.conf` and add this line in it:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"
```

Then restart the Tomcat service.